# IdentityServer6 - redirect to login page failed (404 error)

Tags: asp.net-core, duende-identity-server, identityserver6

Could anyone please help me out regarding issue with Identity Server 6. It is not redirecting
to the login page. Same code-base is working without any issue.

[image]

this end point working means ID server is running on my local:
https://localhost:7080/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: what is your configuration in the client application?  and what returnUri have you defined in IdentityServer?

Comment: Is `localhost:7080` your IdP or your RP?

Comment: "ReturnUrl": "https://localhost:44323/#!/authenticated-callback"

Comment: Your (double-encoded) `redirect_url` looks like `localhost:44323` which is your RP, so `localhost:7080` is your IdP. This looks like a straightforward misconfiguration of your routes in your RP...

Comment: @Sami You have `#!` there... which tells me you're using an SPA... [which won't work](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/). You need to use a "real" web-server to handle OIDC flows.